# How to implement custom / complex operation routes in FeathersJS

Tags: feathersjs

I need to implement a bunch of routes that do very custom / complex operations on a FeathersJS app.

One of those routes is `/Category/disableExclusiveContentsOf/:id`. It runs a query against half a dozen database tables to find rows that relate to the category `:id` exclusively. I absolutely cannot do that using the querying abstractions FeathersJS provides. Then, it uses FeathersJS' "local" API to update the rows I found, so that data update events are fired to clients.

However, if I implement the route using Express alone, Feathers authentication / authorization hooks won't run, so the endpoint won't be protected, which is a requirement.

How can I accommodate such things in a FeathersJS application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can still implement the route using [your own service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html) and use the `:id` as [route parameter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/middleware/routing.html#nested-routes):

```
app.use('/Category/disableExclusiveContentsOf/:id', {
  find() {
    // do complex stuff here
  }
});
```

One thing I'd recommend changing is that the URL seems to be action and not resource oriented. This means that someone can change your application data with a GET request which is generally considered not a good practise (e.g. in some cases the Google crawler came in and deleted/changed a bunch of things).

Feathers encourages you to think in resources rather than custom routes and actions. In your case you would have an `ExclusiveContents` service that you can `POST` to:

```
app.use('/Category/ExclusiveContents/:categoryId', {
  create(data, params) {
    // do complex stuff here
    params.categoryId // the id of the category
    data // -> additional data from the POST request
  }
});
```