# Custom service/route creation using feathersjs

Tags: feathersjs

I have been reading the documentation for last 2 days. I'm new to [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/).

***First issue***: any link related to `feathersjs` is not accessible. Such as [this](https://legacy.docs.feathersjs.com/databases/querying.html).

Giving the following error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> legacy.docs.feathersjs.com redirected you too many times.

Hence I'm unable to traceback to similar types or any types of previously asked threads.

***Second issue***: It's a great framework to start with Real-time applications. But not all real time application just require *alone DB access*, their might be access required to something like Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure etc. In my case it's the same and it's more like problem with setting up routes.

I have executed the following commands:

`feathers generate app`

`feathers generate service` (*service name*: upload, REST, *DB*: Mongoose)

`feathers generate authentication` (*username and password*)

I have the setup with me, ready but **how do I add another custom service?**

The granularity of the service starts in the following way (Use case only for upload):

Conventional way of doing it >> `router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) =>{});`

Assume, I'm sending a `file` using data form, and some extra param like `{ storage: "s3"}` in the req.

Postman --> POST (Only) to `/upload` ---> Process request (`isStorageExistsInRequest?`) --> Then perform the actual upload respectively to the specific Storage in Req and log the details in local db as well --> Send Response (`Success or Failure`)

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641402/5730203) on stack overflow where you have answered with this:

```
app.use('/Category/ExclusiveContents/:categoryId', {
  create(data, params) {
  // do complex stuff here
  params.categoryId // the id of the category
  data // -> additional data from the POST request
 }
});
```

The solution can viewed in this way as well, since `featherjs` supports micro service approach, It would be great to have sub-routes like:

`/upload_s3` -- uploads to s3

`/upload_azure` -- uploads to azure and so on.

`/upload` -- main route which is exposed to users. User requests, process request, call the respective sub-route. (Authentication and Auth to be included as well)

How to solve these types of problems using existing setup of feathersjs?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure sir, I'll not repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is a deployment issue, Netlify is looking into it. The current documentation is not on the legacy domain though, what you are looking for can be found at [docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html).

2) A custom service can be added by running `feathers generate service` and choosing the custom service option. The functionality can then  be implemented in `src/services/<service-name>/<service-name>.class.js` according to the [service interface](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html). For file uploads, an example on how to customize the parameters for [feathers-blob](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-blob) (which is used in the [file uploading guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/file-uploading.html)) can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-blob/issues/21).