# Custom result with feathers

Tags: feathersjs

I have been making an API server with feathers. I have two mongoose services. Now my requirement is I want one API that has a result of both services.
Let's say **product-master** and **product** are two services. The output I want is to merge both services.

To accomplish this I found one way is hook. So I tried this.

```
module.exports = function () {
return function (hook) {
let Product = hook.app.service('product').Model;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  Product.find({}, function(err, products) {
    var productMap = [];
    products.forEach(function(product) {
      productMap.push(products);
    });
    res.send(productMap);
    console.log(productMap);
    resolve(hook);
  });
});
};
};
```

Now I called the hook on before find method of **product-master** But I don't understand how to merge the records of **product** to **product-master** service.

And one more thing is how to create a one different API that has a merged result and custom route like http://localhost:3030/products.

**Update**

I found one post on stackoverflow, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632235/how-to-implement-custom-complex-operation-routes-in-feathersjs/39641402#39641402) might be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways for what I think you want to do. I also recommend not using the models directly but the services you want (by calling their [service methods](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html)). You also want to be familiar with the [API for hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html). Then you have some options:

**1) Modifying the existing results**

To modify the result of an existing service call, modify `hook.result` in an `after` hook:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return function (hook) {
    let productService = hook.app.service('product');

    return productService.find({
      paginate: false // Turn off pagination
    }).then(products => {
      hook.result.products = products;
      return hook;
    });
  };
};
```

Then

```
const myHook = require('../../hooks/myhook');

app.service('products-master').hooks({
  after: {
    get: [ myHook() ]
  }
});
```

This will add a `products` property when getting a single item from the `products-master` service.

**2) Setting `hook.result`**

To skip a database call you can set `hook.result` to what you want to return in a `before` hook. Keep in mind that all `after` hooks will still run.

**3) Using a custom service**

In a [custom service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) you can do whatever you like, for example get all the things you need and put them together manually:

```
app.use('/all-products', {
  find() {
    return this.app.service('products-master').find(params).then(page => {
      const promises = page.data.map(masterProduct => {
        return this.app.service('products').find({
          paginate: false,
          query: {
            masterProductId: masterProduct._id
          }
        }).then(products => {
          // Add to masterProduct
          masterProduct.products = products;
        });
      });

      return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // Return `page` which has the modified data
        return page;
      });
    });
  },

  setup(app) {
    this.app = app;
  }
});
```

In the generator a custom service can be created by choosing `custom service` and modifying the `servicename.class.js`.

**4) The populate hook**

Since I think you just want to populate related entities you can also have a look at the [populate common hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks-common.html#populate). It can do those things automatically.

**5) Using Mongoose `$populate`**

The [Mongoose Feathers adapter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongoose.html) also supports the [$populate query parameter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/mongoose.html#populate) which allows you to pull in relationships that you defined in your Mongoose model.

For more information on associations in Feathers also see [this FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-associations).